# Printing a list on a new line

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that i call a function on to make it print out the list in lexicographic order. Lexicographic is basically a sort() which isn't important but I want this list sorted in a new line with every entry. Right now it just prints like

```
['(011)', '(022)', '(040)', '(04344)', '(044)', '(04546)', '(0471)', '(080)', '(0821)']
```

when i want

```
011
022
etc
```

I tried using a `for` loop but that made it worse. I tried

```
print (lexicographic(uniquelist), sep = '\n')
```

but that didn't change anything. I even tried making a new empty list and appending but that didn't go anywhere the new line feature works without the function "lexicographic" call.

```
print(lexicographic(uniquelist), sep = '\n')

(04344)
(080)
(044)
(011)
(0821)
(022)
(040)
(0471)
(04546)
```

expected this but sorted lexicographically and on a new line

Comment: Are you saying that when you call `print(lexicographic(uniquelist), sep = '\n')` you do not get the list items, one per line, in sorted order?

Comment: yes I get the lexicographic order but not in new line
['(011)', '(022)', '(040)', '(04344)', '(044)', '(04546)', '(0471)', '(080)', '(0821)']
this what i get

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do what you like:

```
uniques = ['(04344)', '(080)', '(044)', '(011)',
           '(0821)', '(022)', '(040)', '(0471)',
          '(04546)']

# Join with new lines and print
print('\n'.join(sorted(uniques)))

# A classic loop, nothing wrong with this
for item in sorted(uniques):
    print(item)
```

Output is:

```
(011)
(022)
(040)
(04344)
(044)
(04546)
(0471)
(080)
(0821)
```

If you do not want the parens,

```
for item in sorted(uniques):
    print(item[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your lexographic function, try doing

```
for l in lexographically_sorted_list:
    print (l)
```

Comment: Somehow, using just a sort fixed and matches with the lexicographic order so I guess i don't need the function at all. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print each element of your list on one line, you can use: `[print(elt) for elt in list]`

Here one example which also remove brackets:

```
list = ['(0821)', '(011)', '(080)', '(022)',  '(04344)', '(040)', '(044)', '(04546)', '(0471)', ]

# sort 
list.sort()

# Print each element per line
[print(elt[1:-1]) for elt in list]
# 011
# 022
# 040
# 04344
# 044
# 04546
# 0471
# 080
# 0821
```

Hope that help !